# How to mock fetch POST request when component mounts

Tags: reactjs, graphql, fetch, react-testing-library

I am trying to mock a fetch POST request as when my application component mounts the fetch request is initiated, so I want to ensure that is has been called and with the correct parameters.  I am using a graphQL query for the POST request data and I am testing through react testing library.

Below is the code used to fetch the data.

Any suggestions on how to test this?

```
const STARSHIP_QUERY = `{
        allStarships {
            starships {
                id
                name
                starshipClass
                maxAtmospheringSpeed
                costInCredits
                passengers
                filmConnection {
                    films {
                        title
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
`

// pull in startships from api
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://connectr-swapi.herokuapp.com/', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify({query: STARSHIP_QUERY})
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        setStarships(data.data.allStarships.starships);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log({'Error': error}))
},[]);
```

Comment: If you are using jest, did you try `global.fetch = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockData)`?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you exactly want to test.

- If you want to test that your frontend sends the right request, I'd say you can take a look at https://www.anthonygonzales.dev/blog/how-to-test-data-fetching-components.html
- If you want to test how your request is handled by the backend, here's a tutorial about testing GraphQL endpoints https://blog.escape.tech/testing-your-graphql-api/